# how to read csv file in drupal 6

Tags: forms

I want to read a simple csv file having 6 rows and 2 columns :

```
   **name   |  value**
    AJW097  |   1
    BDV763  |   1
    PVWC67  |   1
    WPC028  |   1
    TGI0227 |   1
    W5615C  |   1
```

I had saved this file here `sites/default/files/csvfile.csv`

here is the code i am using:

```
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form = array();
  $form['browser'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Browser Upload'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t("Upload a CSV file."),
  );
  $file_size = t('Maximum file size: !size MB.', array('!size' => file_upload_max_size()));
  $form['browser']['upload_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('CSV File'),
    '#size' => 40,
    '#description' => t('Select the CSV file to be upload. ') . $file_size,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Upload CSV File'),
  );

  $form['#attributes']['enctype'] = "multipart/form-data";
  return $form;
}



function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $filepath = $form_state['values']['upload_file']->filepath;
  $fp = fopen($filepath,'r') or die("can't open file");


print "<table>\n";

while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {
    print '<tr>';
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) {
        print '<td>'.$csv_line[$i].'</td>';
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print '</table>';
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
}
```

The problem is it is not reading the file and every time i click on Upload CSV File button it dies and say: can't open file.
where i am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you firstly should save file using [file_save_upload()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6).

Because `$form_state` doesn't consists file contents, just name and original path. Moreover, filepath links to temporary storage, where php might not have access for reading.

Comment: Data import from CSV to drupal 6 is quite easy using using 'node_import' module.

Comment: possible dupicate: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/20014/10216

Answer (score 2):

try function form submit like:

```
function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $line_max = variable_get('user_import_line_max', 1000);
  ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
  $filepath = $form_state['values']['file_upload']->filepath;
  $handle = @fopen($filepath, "r");
  // start count of imports for this upload
  $send_counter = 0;
  while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, $line_max, ',')) {
    // $row is an array of elements in each row
    // e.g. if the first column is the email address of the user, try something like
    $mail = $row[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use different modules to read the data of .csv files into your database:

[Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) (Drupal 6 and 7) or [Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) (Drupal 6)

If you want to transform a .csv file into a table within a node you can use:

TableField (Drupal 6 and 7)

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_module_form($form, $form_state) {

  #prepare the file upload form
  $form = array('#attributes' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));

  #file selector element
  $form['csv'] = array(
      '#type' => 'file',
      '#title' => 'Upload users',
      '#description' => t('Pick a csv file to upload')
  );

  #submit button
  $form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit', 
  '#value' => 'Upload'
  );

   return $form;
}

#handle the form submission
function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  #this leads us to sites/mysite.example.com/files/
  $dir = file_directory_path();

  # unlike form submissions, multipart form submissions are not in 
  # $form_state, but rather in $FILES, which requires more checking
  if(isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES) && $_FILES['files']['size']['csv'] != 0){

    #this structure is kind of wacky
    $name = $_FILES['files']['name']['csv'];

    $size = $_FILES['files']['size']['csv'];

    $type = $_FILES['files']['type']['csv'];


    #this is the actual place where we store the file
    $file = file_save_upload('csv', array() , $dir);
    if($file){
      drupal_set_message("You uploaded $name!");
      drupal_set_message("<pre>". print_r($name, true). "</pre>");
       drupal_set_message("<pre>". print_r($size, true). "</pre>");
        drupal_set_message("<pre>". print_r($type, true). "</pre>");
    }
    else{
        drupal_set_message("Something went wrong saving your file.");
    }
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message("Your file doesn't appear to be here.");
  }
}
```